# Resize widget to full screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create button that can maximize the map widget, an minimize it back.

I can do this with a push to a new screen and pop the screen again when returning, but do anybody know if there's a smarter way, like using flexible or something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way that i can think of is that create a variable for holding the state of the map(isMaximized) and according to this if isMaximized is true give the GoogleMap all the space(wrap it with expanded widget if you are using Column) and use this variable for other widget whether to show it in the UI or not (Means wrap it with visibility Widget).

This was the solution that came in my mind maybe this will not be the optimized way but at least it will work for you.

here is the code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandedWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandedWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExpandedWidget> createState() => _ExpandedWidgetState();
}

class _ExpandedWidgetState extends State<ExpandedWidget> {
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Visibility(
                visible: !isExpanded,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  height: 200,
                  child: const Text("Widget 1"),
                )),
            Visibility(
                visible: !isExpanded,
                child: Container(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 118, 6),
                  height: 100,
                  child: const Text("Widget 2"),
                )),
            Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  height: 100,
                  child: const Text("Map Widget"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
                visible: !isExpanded,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  height: 200,
                  child: const Text("Widget 1"),
                )),
            Visibility(
                visible: !isExpanded,
                child: Container(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 118, 6),
                  height: 100,
                  child: const Text("Widget 2"),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This idea actually work, but some code example would be nice :-)

Comment: check the code is attached with the answer